# DOM touch events on IE/EDGE instead of mousedown

Tags: internet-explorer, events, touch, mouse, microsoft-edge

I'm implementing the following js code for adding events on a Canvas:

```
c.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){console.log('touch')},true);
c.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e) {console.log("mouse")},true);
```

My computer is a hybrid Windows 10 tablet. 
On IE/EDGE, when I perform a mouse click I get 'mouse' log.
On IE/EDGE, when I perform a touch on screen, I get 'mouse' log too.

However, when on IE/EDGE mobile (Windows phone)  or Chrome, I get the 'touch' log when I touch the screen.

I'm convinced that shomehow IE/EDGE, when executed on a laptop, translates "touch" events to 'mouse' events.

Is there any javascript, meta-tag or any option to disable this "translation"?

Note. I'm using touch and mouse events due PIXIJS framework.

Comment: if you're using pixi.js, shouldn't you handle mouse and touch events with pixi.js' Interaction Manager instead? http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.interaction.InteractionManager.html It has its own onMouseDown/onTouchStart events

Comment: the problem is when I add a PIXI touch event. It does not works on desktops, even using a touchscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working on touchevents on EDGE on a laptop, you can stop the translation by changing some settings of the flags. Put about:flags in the browser URL. 
There under the field 
"*Enable touch events*" choose "*Only on when touchscreen is detected*" and under 
"*Fire compatible mouse events in response to the tap gesture*"
choose "*Always Off*"
As shown in pic

[image]

This will disable your automatic translation. Restart the browser and you will start getting touchevents.

Comment: Is possible to programmatically disable it?

Comment: Even I tried but I don't think so it can programmatically be changed, because flags are very browser specific thing as they change the behavior. You can find more details regarding the same here [stackoverflow-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060363/google-chrome-how-can-i-programmatically-enable-chrome-flags-some-of-the-mod)

Answer (score -1):

Staring EdgeHTML 17, Microsoft supports Pointer Events to solve the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159745/9598077