# Is there any way to use a script to enable a single flag on Google Admin Console?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-developers-console, google-chrome-os

So, I am doing a small bit of research for my Google Admin. He and I were trying to figure out how to allow users under the domain to enable the singular flag for Chrome OS Dark Mode, upon request, without unblocking the entire chrome://flags address. He said that there is no way to do it without creating a script.

Anyway, to the point, is there any scripts out there for doing something similar? I can edit the code when I need to in order to make it exactly for what it needs to be, but I do not know what the code (or whatever it is) should be in order for a certain flag to be enabled properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Chrome Management API](https://developers.google.com/chrome/management) has a limited management options to control Chrome OS devices. Upon checking specifically on [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-chrome-devices) that manages Chrome OS devices, you can only manage devices information (e.g. move a device to a different OU or update a device's Chrome OS version). Thus, it is not possible to use script for this, given that Chrome flags are experimental settings on Chrome.

I did some research and found a workaround by using [command line flags (or "switches")](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) where you can set to your Chrome OS devices to auto enable [dark mode switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#force-dark-mode) when user turn on the Chrome OS device. However, you need to [put the device into dev mode, disable rootfs verification, and bring up a command prompt](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/developer_mode.md#chrome-cmdline-flags) to be abe to do this method. Additionally, this also involves changing the file system of the device, which could be not ideal for your setup.

Comment: Definitely don't want to do that, then. Is that the only way?

Comment: I have tried further checking earlier, but there's no other option on Chrome OS for you to manage Chrome flags. You can check the answer from this quite similar post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060363/google-chrome-how-can-i-programmatically-enable-chrome-flags-some-of-the-mod but I highly doubt that it would work on Chrome OS as the post is specifically for Google Chrome browsers (Windows/Mac/Linux).